# WiFi Status 1 on ESP8266

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to connect my Arduino Uno R3 + ESP8266 to a WiFi connection, and it returned a status of 1 when I printed out `WiFi.status()`, does anyone now what does it really mean and what's the solution? Here's my ESP8266 code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

// WiFi CREDENTIALS
const char *ssid = "xxxx";
const char *password = "xxxx";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Connect to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
}
    
void loop(){ 
  delay(5000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Connect to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(WiFi.status());
  Serial.println(WL_CONNECTED);
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    delay(15000);
  }
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("From ESP Connected!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("From ESP Not Connected!");
  }
}
```

=== UPDATE ===
I've tried using my smartphone's hotspot and it worked on the first try.

Comment: see the source code or documentation https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#status

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/da6ec83b5fdbd5b02f04cf143dcf8e158a8cfd36/cores/esp8266/wl_definitions.h#L50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure myself, but when I start over using the cleaner code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

// WiFi CREDENTIALS
const char *ssid = "xxxx";
const char *password = "xxxx";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("From ESP Connected!");
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

My gut is telling me that maybe `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA)` is causing the error?

By the way, it worked already, thanks Juraj and cbalakus for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-println-wifi-status-codes-meaning/486265/2) in Arduino Forum. I hope it is useful for you. And status 1 means no ssid according to enum below.

```
typedef enum {
    WL_NO_SHIELD        = 255,   // for compatibility with WiFi Shield library
    WL_IDLE_STATUS      = 0,
    WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL    = 1,
    WL_SCAN_COMPLETED   = 2,
    WL_CONNECTED        = 3,
    WL_CONNECT_FAILED   = 4,
    WL_CONNECTION_LOST  = 5,
    WL_DISCONNECTED     = 6
} wl_status_t;
```

Comment: this is not up to date. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/da6ec83b5fdbd5b02f04cf143dcf8e158a8cfd36/cores/esp8266/wl_definitions.h#L50